# Order failure in PayPal integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I am doing PayPal integration in my project. Everything is working, but at the end, the payment success method is not generated. My code for payment success is:

```
else if ([response isKindOfClass:[DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails class]]) {    
    DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails *dres = (DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails *)response;
    if (dres.PaymentInfo.count > 0 && ((PaymentInfo *)[dres.PaymentInfo objectAtIndex:0]).TransactionID.length > 0)
    {
        [self paymentSuccess:((PaymentInfo *)[dres.PaymentInfo objectAtIndex:0]).TransactionID];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error came");
        [self paymentFailed];
    }
}
```

and the payment success method is...

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

orderResultsViewController.forDelivery = ((ReviewOrderViewController *)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:navController.viewControllers.count - 2]).forDelivery;
orderResultsViewController.transactionID = transactionID;
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE animated:TRUE];
[navController pushViewController:orderResultsViewController animated:TRUE];
```

If you got it then point me in some direction to go...

```
-(void)paymentFailed {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Order failed" 
                                                    message:@"Your order failed. Touch \"Pay with PayPal\" to try again."
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

I am getting above alert view and payment order failed....

Comment: You have not shown what error you get, I think you posted the question before you finished writing it!

Comment: @AndySinclair I got above last PaymentFailed method. The alert view in that method is coming. because in my first code else condition is called this method.

Comment: @AndySinclair The program should pass from if condition not from else.

Comment: Maybe there is some error information in your dres object, check the documentation for DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails

Comment: @AndySinclair in code PaymentInfo is MutableArrayAccessor. and dres is the object of DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails class. this is inbuilt library class method. thats why i am not getting what to do.

Comment: Can you examine the properties of PaymentInfo and DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails, there must be some status info or error message in these classes - I don't know for sure as it is a while since I did any PayPal API Dev.